# Why does the OLS estimator simplify as follows for the single regressor case?

Tags: st.statistics, estimation-theory, matrices, economics

I was reading in "A Guide to Econometrics" that given $Y = X \beta + \epsilon$, the variance covariance matrix of $\beta^\text{OLS}$ is given by $\sigma^2 (X' X)^{-1}$ where $\sigma^2$ is the variance of the error term...

it then says that in the case of a single regressor $y = \beta_1 + \beta_2 x$, that this simplifies to $\sigma^2 / \sum(x-\bar{x})^2$. I don't quite see this..isn't the matrix $X$ in this case still a two by two matrix? Namely:

$$
X =
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & x_1 \\\
1 & x_2
\end{array}
\right)
$$

How are we getting something like $\sum(x-\bar{x})^2$ ?

Comment: This question would be a better fit at http://math.stackexchange.com, as it has a broader remit than MO; this site is (primarily) for research-level questions.

Comment: Or even http://stats.stackexchange.com, which is more statistics-focussed.